# Envio de arquivo com HTTP-POST

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-post

Ao rodar o script para enviar o arquivo ele me retorna esta mensagem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "modelo.py", line 102, in <module>
filepath = args.filepath
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'filepath'
```

O trecho do código que ele reclama é este que está dentro do modelo.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'c:/users/arquivo',
        help='Caminho completo até o arquivo que se deseja enviar'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'teste',
        help='Nome do método do respectivo arquivo'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'seee',
        help='Nome do usuário cadastrado no sistema'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'sdfgfgdffhgt54828',
        help='Chave secreta que autentica o usuário'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '20190511180000.csv.gz',
        help='Nome do arquivo que será salvo no data lake.'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    **filepath = args.filepath** <-- ESSA É A LINHA 102
    filename = args.filename
    methodname = args.methodname
    username = args.username
    secretkey = args.secretkey

    file_obj = File(filepath, filename)

    # Send data
    file_obj.post(username, methodname, secretkey)
```

Comment: O que exatamente está tentando fazer? A biblioteca `argparse` serve para **criar** uma CLI, mas parece que você está tentando utilizá-la para executar um comando. E onde exatamente entram o `python-requests` e `http-post` que colocou como tag da pergunta?

Comment: Estou enviando um arquivo .gzip para um servidor de analise de dados... Para enviar esse arquivo que será lido, ele tem que estar em gzip e enviado por http-post. No arquivo modelo.py eu tenho os parâmetros de envio, mas quando o executo, ele me retorna a mensagem como se eu não estivesse inserido o args "caminho do arquivo".

Comment: Então você realmente está tentando executar um comando? A biblioteca `argparse` não faz isso.